# How to hide and unhide a Navigation Bar Item on tap?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a tab bar app with an item that's a favorite list. 
When i add a new favorite and select it to open up, it loads the correct nib, but there's the navigation bar that covers some of the text.

How can i do to let the nib show properly without the navigation bar that covers everything? I need it to go back to the favorites list,but it covers some of the text. I was thinking to an hiding \ unhiding on tap, but i've already tried, it hides the main Navigation Bar (the one with Favorites title) too. Any suggests?

Edit:

The code i'm using to call in nibs:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        Favorite *fav = (Favorite *)[[[FavoritesData sharedFavoritesData] getFavorites] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *selectedItem = fav.favId;

        if ([selectedItem isEqualToString:@"First"]) {
            Detail1 *detailViewController = [[Detail1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Detail1" bundle:nil];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
            [detailViewController release];
         }
}
```

I want to hide the Back button item when the nib appears,, and to show it when i tap the screen. And to adapt the nib to the screen, due the nav is kinda transparent.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved everything, there were problems with the Navigation bar Color (i choose Black Transparent instead of Black Opaque),and then the nib was covered by it.  I changed and the nib resized like i wanted. Thanks for the answers btw.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this property to hide the navigation bar:

```
   myNavController.navigationBarHidden = true
```

And just set to false when you want it to show again:

```
   myNavController.navigationBarHidden = false
```

Comment: Where does this snippet go? In the didSelectRowAtIndexPath? I was thinking to show it and hide it on tap.

Comment: @Phillip You can put it in the viewDidLoad of the nib that is loading next after the selection.

Comment: @Phillip in the Detail1  class in the viewDidLoad method set the navigationBarHidden to true.

Comment: The problem is that it hides the navigationBar to both the main Navigation Controller (the one with Categories) and to the favorites list. I want it to hides only when i select it from the Favorites list.

Answer (score 0):

Create two UIButtons yourself and set them to the nav bar. After that, create write an IBAction method that will hide if it was unhidden and it will unhide if it was hidden.